# QCombobox background color for edit part of combobox

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I would like to paint red the background of the combobox when it is closed if there is no selection and back to white on selection.
The list part should be always white but the editor part (top) should be red when empty and white when there an item is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
    QPalette pal = Combo->palette();
    pal.setColor(QPalette::Base,  QColor(Qt::red));
    Combo->setPalette(pal);

    For each item of Combo:

    Combo->insertItem(index, z);
    Combo->setItemData(index, QColor(Qt::white), Qt::BackgroundColorRole);
```

after all the items added:

```
Combo->setCurrentIndex(-1);
```